# Oracle :Compare dates only by the Hour

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

We have a table which has a DATE column d.

I'd like to get all the rows where the d column is greater / lower than some value, regardless of the date.

For example

```
|       d          |
-------------------
|2009/11/1 15:55:23|
--------------------
|2009/11/2 15:55:23|
--------------------
|2009/11/3 15:55:23|
--------------------
|2009/11/3 17:55:23|
--------------------
```

For example, If I want all the records marked after 5 PM:

```
select d 
 from my_table 
where extract( hour from d ) > TO_DATE ('17:00:00','HH24:MI:SS')
```

This should return only one record

```
|2009/11/3 17:55:23|
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but I get an error on the extract function:

```
ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source 
Cause: The extract source does not contain the specified extract field.
```

Is there a better way to do this?
Whats up with that error? extract only available for sysdate, as in all examples i've found?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So did you find a generic solution, working with the HOUR field and EXTRACT? I need a cross DBMS compatible solution for this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about this?

```
select d 
from my_table
where to_char(d,'HH24') > '16';
```

Comment: By the way, 'hour' only supported for timestamp type based on google search. 

Is performance matter for this case? Just curious.

Comment: Consider a function-based index on the expression above: `CREATE INDEX my_table_fbi01 on my_table (to_char(date_col, 'HH24'));` However, given your example, performance would probably still be unoptimal. Assuming no variance in the hourly pattern of your date column, you'd still be getting 1/3 of the data back, so an index wouldn't help you there.

Answer (score 9):

Don't have an Oracle database to test with at the moment but I think the following should work:

```
SELECT *
  FROM MY_TABLE t
  WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(t.D AS TIMESTAMP)) > 16;
```

But I don't understand why the CAST would be needed as [this page](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#i54330) says that HOUR is a valid field in a DATE.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: This [page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions052.htm) explains why you need cast to TIMESTAMP: _"EXTRACT interprets expr as an ANSI datetime datatype. For example, EXTRACT treats DATE not as legacy Oracle DATE but as ANSI DATE, without time elements."_

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
select d from my_table 
where (d-trunc(d)) > 16/24;
```